# Mondial database in all languages

Tags: mysql, database, api

I'm looking (if exist!) for new turistic portal a web service (API) for have:
Country name, province, city and longitude in the world. But I want this in every languages; for example: italy, italia, italie, italien ecc  the same for world cities: roma, rome, rom ecc ecc.

Is possible to have it?

:-(